# Asus F555U compatible WiFi card

Tags: laptop, wifi, network-adapter

I want to replace the internal modem in my laptop with a better one because right now I drop out of every network all the time. Currently an Atheros ar5b125 (Half Mini PCI-E) is built in and I was wondering if you have any recommendations for a high-quality WiFi card suitable for my laptop?